After running bash script (.sh) file, the process does not come back to the docker compose entry point
I have some spring boot microservices. I want to run them using docker compose. To be sure that services run in order, I have used a .sh file to run one of them before others because other microservices depend on it.
The bash script file runs very well but it stops the caller container.
I searched on Internet and realized that some commands must be added at the end of the bash script file: /cnb/process/web or ./cnb/lifecycle/launcher in order to continue the process. But this message is shown:  /cnb/process/web: No such file or directory.
Spring boot version: 3.2.2
Docker compose: 3.8
.sh file:
#!/bin/bash
# check-config-server-started.sh

apt-get update -y
yes | apt-get install curl

curlResult=$(curl -s -o -I -w "%{http_code}" http://cloud-config-server:8888/actuator/health)

echo "result status code:" "$curlResult"

while [[ ! $curlResult == "200" ]]; do
  >&2 echo "Config server is not up yet!"
  sleep 2
  curlResult=$(curl -s -o -I -w "%{http_code}" http://cloud-config-server:8888/actuator/health)
done
/cnb/process/web
#./cnb/lifecycle/launcher

Docker compose file:
version: "3.8"

services:
  cloud-config-server:
    container_name: cloud-config-server-container
    build:
      dockerfile: ./cloud-config-server/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    environment:
      - "SERVER_PORT=8888"
    networks:
      my-compose-net:
    restart: on-failure

  webapp:
    container_name: webapp-container
    build:
      dockerfile: ./webapp/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
      - "./check-config-server-started.sh:/usr/local/bin/check-config-server-started.sh"
    user: root
    entrypoint: [ "check-config-server-started.sh" ]
    environment:
      - "SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://cloud-config-server:8888"
    depends_on:
      - cloud-config-server
    networks:
      my-compose-net:
    restart: on-failure

networks:
  my-compose-net:


I have faced with the same problem. I mean keeping containers running after executing .sh files by adding /cnb/process/web to the .sh file. It seems the problem originates from the way you create your docker image. In the docker compose file instead of using
build:
dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
I create docker images using spring boot pom.xml by adding these codes:
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <name>${project.groupId}/my.service:${project.version}</name>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-image</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

then mvn clean install to create an image.
after that you can refer to the image in the docker compose:
image: your-image-name

instead of
build:
  dockerfile: ./Dockerfile


Thank you @Pezhman. It solved my problem and works.

Append this line to the end of your .sh file tail -f /dev/null
Because when your .sh exits, nothing keeps the docker container running.
You can use another equivalent command.
See https://kodekloud.com/blog/keep-docker-container-running/

I checked these methods and seems they should work, But did not solve my issue

You should use the facilities available in compose instead of reinventing them.
depends on has the option service_healthy to check whether the service you depend on is healthy. You may need to provide a helathcheck on your service but that would be trivial in your case.

I tried it but I do not know why it is not working for me. I am really confused.
